# Open and Close InfoWindow onclick

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

Can anyone help me code inside my eventListener so that an infowindow will do the following:
    open if it's currently closed,
and close if it's currently open.

I've tried the following to no success...

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
if(infowindow.closed == true){
infowindow.open(map, marker)
}
else{
infowindow.close(map, marker)
}
})
```

Comment: Are you really using the [deprecated (and turned off) Google Maps Javascript API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
    infoWindowClosed = true;

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        if (infoWindowClosed) {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
            infoWindowClosed = false;
        } else {
            infowindow.close(map, marker)
            infoWindowClosed = true;
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentInfoWindow = null; 

then on every marker click event I do something like this: 

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ 
    content: "your content here" 
}); 
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { 
    if (currentInfoWindow != null) { 
        currentInfoWindow.close(); 
    } 
    infowindow.open(map, marker); 
    currentInfoWindow = infowindow; 
});
```

Source : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/cA2VRg4TO1k

Answer (score 0):

Try first close infow window, and then get click to open again:

```
<script>
var onMarkerClick = function() {
  var marker = this;
  var latLng = marker.getPosition();
  infoWindow.setContent('<h3>Marker position is:</h3>' +
      latLng.lat() + ', ' + latLng.lng());

  infoWindow.open(map, marker);
};

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
  infoWindow.close();
});

var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(37.789879, -122.390442)
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', onMarkerClick);
</script>
```

For more information visit the source code from this url:

- http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/single-infowindow/single-infowindow.html